# How to migrate 4TB data to AWS RDS

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, database-migration, rds

I have a requirement to move on premise db to RDS with minimum downtime

Approx data size is 4 TB. AWs snowball takes time to reach and customer cant afford that much time.

Comment: Have you looked at Amazon's database migration service? https://aws.amazon.com/dms/ If you're mirating 4TB, Snowball is overkill, it's designed for petabyte scale, not terabyte scale.

Comment: Thanks i need to try this